# Does macOS delete files in /tmp periodically?

Tags: macos

I notice that even when my Mac machine is not restarted. Files in /tmp more than a few days will disappear. Does macOS periodically purge files in /tmp?

My macOS is 11.4.

Comment: Use the source, Luke:  /etc/periodic/daily/110.clean-tmps !

Answer (score 21):

The [answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413272/what-does-each-one-of-the-sudo-periodic-options-do) suggests that the periodic daily script indeed deletes older files in /tmp.

It is triggered by `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist` which seems to run `/usr/sbin/periodic` daily (via a wrapper).

From the configuration file (`/etc/defaults/periodic.conf`):

```
# 110.clean-tmps
daily_clean_tmps_enable="YES"           # Delete stuff daily
daily_clean_tmps_dirs="/tmp"            # Delete under here
daily_clean_tmps_days="3"               # If not accessed for
daily_clean_tmps_ignore=".X*-lock .X11-unix .ICE-unix .font-unix .XIM-unix"
daily_clean_tmps_ignore="$daily_clean_tmps_ignore quota.user quota.group"
                                        # Don't delete these
```

So anything which hasn't been accessed in the last three days will be deleted (unless it matches a name in `daily_clean_tmps_ignore`).

Answer (score 9):

There is [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585-SW15), which states the following:

- `/tmp`

  This directory is used for general shared temporary storage. It is cleared out each time the system starts up.
- `/var/tmp`

  This directory is used for general shared temporary storage. Although you should not count on data stored in this directory being permanent, unlike `/tmp`, the `/var/tmp` directory is currently not cleared out on reboot.

**Note**: The document is Copyright © 2016 by Apple Inc, which makes the information about 6 years old at the time this answer was posted.

### Other References

- [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
- [How long are files kept in /var/tmp/, and how to use the directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/168125/how-long-are-files-kept-in-var-tmp-and-how-to-use-the-directory)
- [What is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp)

Comment: Although the document is old and in an archive area it is still probably current as Apple has not produced any general documentation since moving these to an archive, ie nothing has replaced them. Also the Unix underpinnings have been there since 1990 and I don't think have chnaged.

Comment: Is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp specific to Apple's unix? Or it applies to other variant of UNIX, like Linux, etc.?

Comment: The difference between `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` is not specific to Apple's Unix. See Other References in my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the `periodic.conf(5)` manual page suggests that the `daily_clean_tmps_enable` option exists to control whether `/tmp` is periodically cleaned, it seems to have been removed in macOS 14.0.

Instead, there is a new `tmp_cleaner` script in `/usr/libexec/tmp_cleaner` that achieves the same thing. It does not appear configurable however.

To disable periodic cleaning of the `/tmp` directory, run the following command:

```
sudo launchctl disable system/com.apple.tmp_cleaner
```

On versions before macOS 14.0, one can configure `periodic.conf` to prevent cleaning:

```
echo 'daily_clean_tmps_enable="NO"' | sudo tee /etc/periodic.conf
```